# Has anyone used Bootleg Biology? Any experience with catching/ growing wild yeast strains?

Tags: sour, yeast-cultures

I just ordered a kit from their website that is for catching/growing wild yeast strains for home brews. I was wondering if anyone else may have used them or tried doing this their selves. It's one thing to just try and open ferment, but this actually isolates proper strains for less work and better beer. Any advice welcome!